# Why is the href of anchor tag written in code behind not accepting 'aspx'

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json

I have a calender control and on selecting a respective date, I need to display Today's Due and Over due as two section in an accordion. I have written the div for accordion in code behind and set style.css to give the look of Accordion. The data from code behind is converted into json and displayed. The code behind is as follows:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string CalenderBinderAccordian()
        {
            try
            {
                //Code to fetch productGroup is not shown
                foreach (var p in productGroup)
                {
                    var todoCount = 1;
                    string todoString = "";
                    int uniqueID = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
                    todoString = "<div class='accordion vertical'><section id='" + uniqueID + "' style='overflow-y: scroll;'> <h2><a href=#" + uniqueID + "><b>Due Today</b></a></h2>";    
                    foreach (var t in p.todo)
                    {
                        var tempAmt = String.Empty;
                        if ((t.Amount == null) || t.Amount == String.Empty)
                            tempAmt = "0";
                        else
                            tempAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(t.Amount.ToString()).ToString();                          
                        todoString += "<p><div style='padding:5px 0px; border-bottom:dashed 1px #dddddd;'><b>" + todoCount.ToString() + "</b>. " + t.ProductName + "<span style='text-align:right; padding-right:5px;'> $" + tempAmt + "</span><a href='www.google.com' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none;'><b>Pay Now</b></a></div></p>";
                        todoCount++;
                    }
                    todoString += "</section>";   

                    var overDue = temps.Select(x => new { x.DueDate }).Distinct().ToList();
                    int overDueCount = 0;
                    uniqueID = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
                    todoString += "<section id='" + uniqueID + "'> <h2><a href=#" + uniqueID + "><b>Over Due</b></a></h2>";
                    int todoCount1 = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < overDue.Count(); i++)
                    {

                        if ((Convert.ToDateTime(overDue[i].DueDate) - Convert.ToDateTime(p.dates)).Days < 0)
                        {
                            overDueCount++;

                            var overDueList = temps.FindAll(x => x.DueDate.Equals(overDue[i].DueDate)).ToList();
                            foreach (var t in overDueList)
                            {
                                var tempAmt = String.Empty;
                                if ((t.Amount == null) || t.Amount == String.Empty)
                                    tempAmt = "0";
                                else
                                    tempAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(t.Amount.ToString()).ToString();
      //Error occurs when the href is given as aspx                                                           
                                todoString += "<p><div style='padding:5px 0px; border-bottom:dashed 1px #dddddd;'><b>" + todoCount1.ToString() + "</b>. " + t.ProductName + "<span style='text-align:right; padding-right:5px;'> $" + tempAmt + "</span><a href='PaymentDetails.aspx' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none;'><b>Pay Now</b></a></div></p>";
                                todoCount++;
                                todoCount1++;
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    todoString = todoString + "</section></div>\",\"count\":\"" + todoCount + "\"},";
                    jsonString = jsonString + String.Format("{{\"{0}\" : \"{1}\",\"{2}\" : \"{3}", "dates", p.dates, "todo", todoString);

                    if (overDueCount.Equals(0))
                    {
                        jsonString = jsonString.Replace("</section><section id='" + uniqueID + "'> <h2><a href=#" + uniqueID + "><b>Over Due</b></a></h2></section>", "</section>");
                    }  

                }
                jsonString = jsonString.TrimEnd(',');
                jsonString = '[' + jsonString + ']';
               string data= jsonString; JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(productGroup);
                return data;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

//How to data is converted to Json`var tododate = [];`

```
$(window).bind('loaded', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ChartBinder.asmx/CalenderBinderAccordian",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {        
            tododate = JSON.parse(msg.d);

        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });   
});
```

Kindly note when the href is given as www.google.com the functionality works well but when it is given as PaymentGateway.aspx It does not display date in accordion format rather shows error alert.

Comment: which error was it again?

Comment: im afraid the opening and closing tags are not matched. is it really the closing todoString is not "</section></div>"?

Comment: @Vogel612: the error alert is displayed.

Comment: @bondythegreat: I checked in HTML Visualizer(code behind) and the div is closed properly.To be frank, when I change the href to 'www.google.com' it works fine.

Comment: @psobhan this means the JSON has some error in it... sorry i am out now, but please write this to the post for the others ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Firebug, Noticed the following Error:
Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property 
Solution: Tried changing the configuration :

```
<configuration> 
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
  </webServices>
</scripting>
```